Image creation in Latex

How do I create this image using latex?

One way is start reading and trying Tikz, tikz.dev

You can use quickly https://www.mathcha.io/editor:

\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}, % Imposta la larghezza predefinita delle linee
  circle/.style={fill=black, fill opacity=1},  % Stile per il cerchio
  ellipse/.style={fill=black, fill opacity=1}  % Stile per l'ellisse
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt, y=0.75pt, yscale=-1, xscale=1]
% Cerchio
\draw [circle] (91.4,95.3) .. controls (91.4,69.18) and (112.58,48) .. (138.7,48)
    .. controls (164.82,48) and (186,69.18) .. (186,95.3) .. controls (186,121.42)
    and (164.82,142.6) .. (138.7,142.6) .. controls (112.58,142.6) and (91.4,121.42) .. (91.4,95.3) -- cycle;
% Ellisse
\draw [ellipse] (219.36,205.29) .. controls (213.64,201.14) and (231.44,166.83) .. (259.13,128.66)
    .. controls (286.82,90.5) and (313.91,62.92) .. (319.63,67.08) .. controls (325.36,71.23)
    and (307.55,105.54) .. (279.87,143.71) .. controls (252.18,181.87) and (225.09,209.44) .. (219.36,205.29) -- cycle;
% Curva rossa
\draw [red] (188,62.6) .. controls (232.33,57.67) and (230.08,50.81) .. (273.96,88.83);
\draw [shift={(276,90.6)}, rotate=221.01] [fill=red, opacity=1, line width=0.08] 
    (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle;
% Linea blu
\draw [blue] (241.76,215.57) -- (301.06,133.64) -- (336.24,85.03);
\draw [shift={(338,82.6)}, rotate=125.9] [fill=blue, opacity=1, line width=0.08] 
    (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle;
\draw [shift={(240,218)}, rotate=305.9] [fill=blue, opacity=1, line width=0.08] 
    (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle;
% Linea blu diagonale
\draw [blue] (206.61,207.19) -- (220.39,217.41);
\draw [shift={(220.39,217.41)}, rotate=36.54] [blue, line width=0.75] 
    (10.93,-4.9) .. controls (6.95,-2.3) and (3.31,-0.67) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.67) and (6.95,2.3) .. (10.93,4.9);
\draw [shift={(206.61,207.19)}, rotate=216.54] [blue, line width=0.75] 
    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Thank you. However, users should be aware that the code created is less optimal, i.e. more complicated than it has to be.

@MS-SPO Dearest, I have  simply understood that the OP not an expert and did not want to waste time. Obviously, my response holds little significance.

Thank you so much
